# Is userdata_file available in salt-cloud vmware provider

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

I want `salt-cloud` with vmware provider to spawn windows minions. But i struggle with the instructions in the documentation.

> If supported by the cloud provider, a PowerShell script may be used to open up this port automatically, using the cloud provider's userdata. The following script would open up port 445, and apply the changes

Does my provider supports the `userdata_file`? I did not find anything in the docs. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the VMware SaltCloud driver, it looks like the `vim.vm.customization.UserData()` section is yet to support execution of PowerShell scripts.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/cloud/clouds/vmware.py#L2631